# InAppSettingsKit textfield

Tags: ios, iphone, settings, inappsettingskit

I have a view Controller which displays my InAppSettingsKit. There I have a textfield. The problem is, the settingsChanged event is fired at every keytroke. Can I change it, so the user has to press return / done / remove the fokus from the textfield?

In this textfield the user should enter the size of the cache of my app. So lets asume the cache size is 128 MB so the textfield will contain 128 if the user wants to change it to 256 MB he would delete the 128 and enter the 256. In the current mode the returned numbers will be

```
128 --> 12 --> 1 --> " " --> 2 --> 25 --> 256
```

That's not the solution I want to achive. I want

```
128 --> 256
```

How can I get it this way?

Greetings
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Just use the new value only after the settings view controller is dismissed.

Comment: This could be a solution but the problem is, that the first responder is removed from the textField so you have to activate the textfield after every char you have entered...

Comment: This would be a bug. Can you reproduce this in the sample app?

Comment: Thats the problem, I can't reproduce it in the Demo App, so I don't know where my error could be.... I transfered the Demo App almost into to my App but everytime I enter a char into a textfield the keyboard is dissmissed and the text field isn't the first responder anymore...

Comment: Ok the Bug was, that we reloaded the table view by ourself after the change (what isn't neccessary...)